# C# HttpClient adding "User-Agent" header shows up as several different headers

Tags: c#, asp.net

When adding a "User-Agent" header to `HttpClient` it shows up as several User-Agent headers instead in the request. It seems as the string added as User-Agent breaks upon a space character by default and then they are added as separate User-Agents. How can I add a single User-Agent string with spaces using `HttpClient`?

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");
//Did not work either, same result
//httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");
//httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not worry about that. It splits your user agent into several parts internally, because that is how User-Agent header defined in [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> The User-Agent request-header field contains information about the
>   user agent originating the request. This is for statistical purposes, 
>   the tracing of protocol violations, and automated recognition of user 
>   agents for the sake of tailoring responses to avoid particular user
>   agent limitations. User agents SHOULD include this field with
>   requests. The field can contain multiple product tokens (section 3.8) 
>   and comments identifying the agent and any subproducts which form a
>   significant part of the user agent. By convention, the product tokens 
>   are listed in order of their significance for identifying the
>   application.
>
> User-Agent     = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )

So what you see are those "product tokens" and if you explore each - you will see that they have `Product` and `Comment` properties.

However, this does **not** mean it will send this as 6 headers. It will send one `User-Agent` header, same as you provided as string.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I saw it was one `User-Agent` header when I checked the outgoing request via proxy.